# Add custom table field in layered navigation

Tags: magento-1.9, layered-navigation, custom

I need help. I have created custom tables and its fields. Like create doctor table and in doctor table  `product_id`  is working as foreign_key and it's column name like     `shift_time`  etc. There are columns in doctor table. So I need this custom column in layered navigation and it's filter. So how can i achieve this functionality? Any tutorial ? Any hint ?

Answer (score 0):

i recommended this tutorial for adding the custom filter

http://www.techytalk.info/create-custom-layered-navigation-filter-magento/